# Does FIR filter remove DC offset properly?

Tags: filters, finite-impulse-response, infinite-impulse-response, digital-filters

I was checking FIR and IIR filter for offset removal. But I found that FIR can not remove DC offset properly. I think there's something more to do with the filter coefficients of FIR to remove DC offset properly. The Octave code is attached here too. I's almost similar to MATLAB.
[image]

```
clear all;
pkg load signal;

fs = 2000;
ts = 1/fs;
N = 500;
t = [0:N-1]*ts;

cutoff_frequency = 50;
fcl = cutoff_frequency - (cutoff_frequency/2);
fch = cutoff_frequency + (cutoff_frequency/2);

f_test = 50; 
f_1  = sin(2*pi()*f_test*t);
f_2 = .3*sin(2*pi()*f_test*10*t);
Offset = 1.7;

f = Offset + f_1 + f_2;

Wl = 2*(fcl/fs);
Wh = 2*(fch/fs); 
Wm = 2*(cutoff_frequency/fs); 

FIR_order = 20;
fc = [0 Wl Wm Wh 1];
m = [0 .03 1 .03 0];
fir_coeff = fir2(FIR_order,fc,m);
filtered_FIR = filter(fir_coeff, 1, f);

IIR_Order = 1;
[b, a] = butter(IIR_Order,[Wl, Wh]);
filtered_IIR = filter(b, a, f);

hold on;
figure 01;
plot(f);
plot(filtered_FIR);
plot(filtered_IIR);
hold off;
```

Comment: Try plotting `fir_coeff`, or even `freqz(fir_coeff)`, see if that fits a highpass FIR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DC offset will only be removed if the filter does not pass DC. If the filter is a low pass filter, then the DC portion of the signal will pass through, scaled by the gain of the filter.

To completely remove DC, the filter would have a zero at $z=1$, which will provide a null at DC. You can expect to see an initial time transient but in the settled state DC will be completely removed if the filter has a zero at $z=1$.

Alternatively, to implement DC with a very simple IIR filter consider the DC Nulling Filter demonstrated and detailed in these posts:

[What does correcting IQ do?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/40734/what-does-correcting-iq-do/40740#40740)

[Transfer function of second order notch filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31028/transfer-function-of-second-order-notch-filter/31030#31030)

Comment: I'll check that. I cannot upvote the comment because this account doesn't have enough points.

Comment: Yes the filter was not actually high pass due to low order. The issue was solved when I changed the order to 200.

Comment: In general for an FIR of any order, if you multiply the transfer function by (z-1)/z, you will get the necessary null st DC but the transition to your passband may not be tight enough and for that reason you would increase the order. I have other links posted on very efficient IIR implementations for DC nulling filters that are typically used (1 delay and 1 feedback, two multipliers). Search “DC Nulling Filter” and you should find it.

Comment: ok I'm checking it.

Comment: @thinkrafi I added the links in the question as it turns out they weren't as simple to find I think.