Designing narrow-band notch filter with high sampling frequency
I want to design a narrow-band filter for a signal that has been sampled at 125 [kHz].
The specifications are:

Passbandfrequency1: 58 [Hz]
Stopbandfrequency1: 59 [Hz]
Stopbandfrequency2: 61 [Hz]
Passbandfrequency2: 62 [Hz]

Ripples are standard, and attenuation 60 [dB].
I'd love to hear if you have any suggestions what is best to do so without needing to downsample.
Thanks

what are "standard" ripples? Exact ripple specification will make a huge difference here. What's your definition of the pass band edge? -3dB or "same as ripple" ? If this is about getting rid of AC line noise, there are better methods

Does this help: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/86660/21048

If I remember correctly, filters with narrow transition bands are good candidates for multirate filtering. Essentially downsampling the signal via a number of filtered downsamplers until you have a narrow band encapsulating the notch, then do a low rate/order bandcut filter, then  a number of upsamplers to return to the original samplerate

A 5th order elliptic filter can theoretically do that (With a ripple of 1 dB)
fs = 125e3;
[z,p,k] = ellip(5,1,60,[58 62]*2/fs,'stop');

A filter that aggressive will have a lot of tradeoffs: the impulse response will be insanely long and there are serious stability concerns.

