# Design and a notch filter using two Butterworth filters in parallel (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, filter-design, lowpass-filter, bandwidth, butterworth

I am doing a project to filter out a 1kHz noise inserted to a 30sec .wav audio file. 
To filter out the 1kHz noise, I am required to design using two Butterworth filters connected in parallel where one is a low pass and the other is a high pass Butterworth Filter.

I have tried to notch out the 1kHz noise by setting the bandwidth to (+/-10Hz) of the 1kHz noise. 
Therefore, the range of the noise signal to be attenuated will be from 990Hz to 1010Hz.

I am planning to obtain the transfer function in s-domain first and then transform it to z-domain.

The designed transfer function will be inputted into MATLAB and the filtered audio file will be obtained.

May I know the steps in designing this filter? Cost-effectiveness and ease of implementation of the filter is emphasised.

Thanks.

Comment: Please see this link for the design of a 2nd order notch filter that may be easier and more cost-effective: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31028/transfer-function-of-second-order-notch-filter/31030#31030

Answer (score 1):

> Cost-effectiveness and ease of implementation of the filter is emphasised.

It that's a your goal then you really shouldn't be using two Butterworth filters. Use a notch filter instead. If there is a "requirement" to use other filters, please explain why this is required. I think your best bet here is to change the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

We discuss IIR notch filter design in this [article](http://www.advsolned.com/practical-noise-reduction-tips-for-biomedical-ecg-datasets/), which may help.