How to implement a realtime filter for an arbitrary waveform?
I am unfamiliar with digital signal processing and would like help with the following roadblock I encountered.
I am comparing phases of two clocks using a Digital Dual Mixer Time Difference (DDMTD) implementation (Moreira, Pedro, et al. "Digital dual mixer time difference for sub-nanosecond time synchronization in Ethernet." 2010 IEEE international frequency control symposium. Available online from the white rabbit website).
Due to some facets of the implementation, I have undesired oscillations with periods (16ns/frequency offset between clocks in ns/S).
For example:


As you could notice , lower harmonics of this noise is also present in the output.
How can I remove this unwanted noise from my output in realtime? The clock freqeuncy differences I can determine after measuring for some duration. I want this filter to activate and utilise the clock differnce data I provide to filter out noise.
Can anyone point me towards the right direction to approach this problem?

This may help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aq_SOvR1Sxs which is a real time implementation of a notch filter on an MCU based on this post: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/31030/21048
